# What does x do in meaning of "how it works"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I would like know is there a question-answer type in german like following:

> What does a norm-referenced test do? (Was sorgt ein normbezogener Test für?)
>
> It compares students’ performance to that of a sample group. (Er vergleicht Leistung des Schülers in Bezug auf die Leistung anderer Probengruppe.)

Does my choose "sorgen für" and "in Bezug auf die Leistung anderer Probengruppe" work for the translation?

Comment: Wofür sorgt ein Test? Er vergleicht DIE Leistung des Schülers in Bezug auf die --(andere)-- Probegruppe. Der einzelne Schüler selbst ist ja keine Probegruppe (eher: Kontrollgruppe). Was ist die Frage?

Comment: @userunknown It was my mistake, I meant "auf die Leistung anderer Probengruppe".

Comment: Dann: Er vergleicht DIE Leistung des Schülers in Bezug auf die L. DER anderen PG. Und: WOFÜR sorgt e. n. Test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use "Wofür sorgt ein Test?", but "Wozu ist ein Test gut?".

> Für jemanden sorgen

means to *take care of* someone, and

> Für etwas sorgen

means to actively make sure something gets done or happens.

> Das Benzin sorgt dafür, dass der Motor läuft.

This isn't the case with a test, which is not active by itself. Only once you administer it, something happens. Hence I'd say

> Wozu dient ein norm-bezogener Test?
>
> Zum Vergleich der Leistungen eines Schülers mit den Leistungen einer Vergleichsgruppe.